# Fragmentos do Thymeleaf não são inseridos

Tags: java, spring, spring-boot, spring-mvc, thymeleaf

Olá. Estou tentando fazer uma simples importação de um trecho de código via `th:insert` do thymeleaf, porém algo não está saindo bem. Pelo que li na documentação, não me parece ter nada de errado, porém, por ser novo utilizando-o, acredito que possa ter deixado algo escapar. Declaro o trecho dessa forma no arquivo header.html:

```
<header th:fragment="menu">
    ...
</header>
```

e faço a importação dessa maneira no meu arquivo simpleHome.html:

```
<div th:insert="~{header :: menu}"></div>
```

Quando reinicio o projeto e abro o navegador, a interpretação ocorre assim:

[image: inserir a descrição da imagem aqui]

ou seja, ele não entende como deveria de fato entender.

```
@Configuration
public class ConfiguracaoSpringMVC extends WebMvcConfigurerAdapter {

    //Esse método configura o thymeleaf
    @Bean
    public SpringTemplateEngine templateEngine (SpringResourceTemplateResolver resolver){
        SpringTemplateEngine templateEngine = new SpringTemplateEngine();
        templateEngine.setTemplateResolver(resolver);
        return templateEngine;
    }

    @Override
    public void addViewControllers (ViewControllerRegistry registry){
        registry.addRedirectViewController("/","animais/listar");
        registry.addRedirectViewController("/home","animais/listar");
    }
}
```

HTML do header:

```
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html lang="pt-br" xmlns:th="http://www.thymeleaf.org">>
<head>
    <meta charset="UTF-8">
    <title>Title</title>
</head>
<body>
<header th:fragment="menu">
    <nav class="alteracoes-navbar navbar navbar-expand-lg">
        <div class="container">
            <ul class="navbar-nav mr-auto">
                <li class="nav-item">
                    <a href="" class="nav-link"><img src="../img/logo_superior1.png" width="50" height="50"
                                                     alt="CatDog"/></a>
                </li>
                <li class="liindex nav-item">
                    <a th:href="@{/ocorrencias/listar}" class="alink nav-link">Ocorrências</a>
                </li>
                <li class="liindex nav-item">
                    <a href="contato.html" class="alink nav-link">Contato</a>
                </li>
                <li class="liindex nav-item">
                    <a href="outros/localizacao.html" class="alink nav-link">Localização</a>
                </li>
                <li class="liindex nav-item">
                    <a href="sobre.html" class="alink nav-link">Sobre nós</a>
                </li>
                <li class="liindex nav-item">
                    <button type="button" class="btnpadrao btn btn-sm" data-toggle="modal" data-target="#loginModal">
                        Entrar
                    </button>
                </li>
                <li class="lifacebook nav-item">
                    <a target="_blank" href="https://www.facebook.com/groups/275221866151012/"><img
                            class="imgimagemfacebook" src="../img/facebook.png"/></a>
                </li>
            </ul>
        </div>
    </nav>
</header>
</body>
</html>
```

HTML do simpleHome:

```
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html lang="pt-br"
      xmlns:th="http://www.thymeleaf.org"
      xmlns:sec="http://www.thymeleaf.org/thymeleaf-extras-springsecurity4"
      xmlns:div="http://www.w3.org/1999/html">
<head th:fragment="cabecalho">
    <meta charset="UTF-8"/>
    <meta name="viewport" content="width=device-width, initial-scale=1"/>
    <meta http-equiv="x-ua-compatible" content="ie=edge"/>
    <title>CatDog</title>
    <link href="../css/style.css" rel="stylesheet"/>
    <link href="/webjars/bootstrap/4.1.0/css/bootstrap.min.css" rel="stylesheet"/>
</head>
<body class="body-config">
<div th:insert="~{header :: menu}"></div>
<main class="main-config">
    <div style="background-color: white" class="centralizado jumbotron fundoprincipal">
        <div th:if="animais != null" class="container">
            <div class="row">
                <div th:each="animal : ${listaDeAnimais}" class="col-sm-6 col-md-4">
                    <div class="card-config card">
                        <img src="../img/gatopainel.png" class="card-img-top" alt="Foto do animal"/>
                        <div class="card-body">
                            <h5 class="card-title" th:text="${animal.nomeAnimal}"></h5>
                            <p class="card-text" th:text="${animal.historiaAnimal}"></p>
                            <p class="card-text">
                                <small class="text-muted">Postado em</small>
                                <small th:text="${animal.dataEncontroAnimal}"></small>
                                <small th:text="${animal.idAnimal}" hidden="hidden"></small>
                            </p>
                        </div>
                    </div>
                </div>
            </div>
        </div>
    </div>
</main>

<!--Corrigir a forma como está buscando os scripts-->
<script src="../js/jquery-3.3.1.min.js"></script>
<script src="https://maxcdn.bootstrapcdn.com/bootstrap/4.0.0-alpha.6/js/bootstrap.min.js"
        integrity="sha384-vBWWzlZJ8ea9aCX4pEW3rVHjgjt7zpkNpZk+02D9phzyeVkE+jo0ieGizqPLForn"
        crossorigin="anonymous"></script>
</body>
</html>
```

Estrutura do projeto:

[image: inserir a descrição da imagem aqui]

Pom.xml:

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8"?>
<project xmlns="http://maven.apache.org/POM/4.0.0"
         xmlns:xsi="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema-instance"
         xsi:schemaLocation="http://maven.apache.org/POM/4.0.0 http://maven.apache.org/xsd/maven-4.0.0.xsd">
    <modelVersion>4.0.0</modelVersion>

    <groupId>br.com.welberdev</groupId>
    <artifactId>ajudaf</artifactId>
    <version>1.0-SNAPSHOT</version>

    <!--Aqui foi declarada a versão do spring e, portanto, as dependencias não precisam-->
    <parent>
        <groupId>org.springframework.boot</groupId>
        <artifactId>spring-boot-starter-parent</artifactId>
        <version>1.5.10.RELEASE</version>
    </parent>
    <!--Fim-->

    <properties>
        <java.version>1.8</java.version>
    </properties>

    <dependencies>

        <!--Dependências padrão para o Spring. (O starter garante um pacote com tudo que precisamos, sem aquele monte de importações)-->
        <dependency>
            <groupId>org.springframework.boot</groupId>
            <artifactId>spring-boot-starter-web</artifactId>
        </dependency>
        <dependency>
            <groupId>org.springframework.boot</groupId>
            <artifactId>spring-boot-starter-data-jpa</artifactId>
        </dependency>
        <dependency>
            <groupId>org.springframework.boot</groupId>
            <artifactId>spring-boot-starter-thymeleaf</artifactId>
        </dependency>
        <dependency>
            <groupId>org.springframework.boot</groupId>
            <artifactId>spring-boot-starter-security</artifactId>
        </dependency>
        <!--Fim-->

        <dependency>
            <groupId>org.webjars</groupId>
            <artifactId>bootstrap</artifactId>
            <version>4.1.0</version>
        </dependency>
        <dependency>
            <groupId>mysql</groupId>
            <artifactId>mysql-connector-java</artifactId>
        </dependency>
    </dependencies>

    <build>
        <plugins>
            <!--Plugin para comunicação do spring com o maven-->
            <plugin>
                <groupId>org.springframework.boot</groupId>
                <artifactId>spring-boot-maven-plugin</artifactId>
            </plugin>
            <!--Fim-->
        </plugins>
    </build>
</project>
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Utilizei a tag `th:replace` e funcionou.